# Get only unique elements from a list

Tags: c#, linq, list, group-by, unique

Have a list with deviceIds and corresponding actions to be taken on device.

```
var results= new List<Result>
{
    new Result{ DeviceId= 1, ActionType = 1 },
    new Result{ DeviceId= 1, ActionType = 2 },
    new Result{ DeviceId= 1, ActionType = 3 },
    new Result{ DeviceId= 2, ActionType = 1 },
    new Result{ DeviceId= 3, ActionType = 1 },
    new Result{ DeviceId= 4, ActionType = 1 },
    new Result{ DeviceId= 5, ActionType = 1 },
    new Result{ DeviceId= 6, ActionType = 1 },
    new Result{ DeviceId= 6, ActionType = 2 },

};
```

How do I filter deviceIds unique in the list(no DeviceId 1), and assign it back to var "results"

```
results = List<Result>
{
    new Result{ DeviceId= 2, ActionType = 1 },
    new Result{ DeviceId= 3, ActionType = 1 },
    new Result{ DeviceId= 4, ActionType = 1 },
    new Result{ DeviceId= 5, ActionType = 1 },
};
```

Have tried using groupby and couldn't move forward

```
   results =  from result in results
              group result by result.DeviceId
              into groupedResultsByDevice
              where groupedResultsByDevice.Count() == 1
              select ????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides answer with query syntax, in method syntax LINQ query it will be:

```
results = results.GroupBy(r => r.DeviceId)
                 .Where(g => g.Key != 1 && g.Count() == 1)
                 .Select(g => g.First())
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: What is the significance of g.Key !=1

Comment: @canceo, I thought you want to filter it out but now I am not even sure why I thought that.. So you can remove this condition simply.

Answer (score 1):

```
results =  from r in results
           group r by r.DeviceId into g
           where g.Count() == 1
           select g.First()
```

You can make it a little bit more efficient replacing `g.Count()` with `!g.Skip(1).Any()`:

```
results =  from r in results
           group r by r.DeviceId into g
           where !g.Skip(1).Any()
           select g.First()
```

It will return `false` as soon as second element is found, instead of counting all items in the group.

Comment: Why not `select g.Single()`?

Comment: if `g is empty` then `!g.Skip(1).Any()` also `true`?

Answer (score 1):

After grouping you can select the first (and only element of the group):

```
results =  from result in results
          group result by result.DeviceId
          into groupedResultsByDevice
          where groupedResultsByDevice.Count() == 1
          select groupedResultsByDevice.First(); // <---
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var results = new List<Result>
                          {
                              new Result {DeviceId = 1, ActionType = 1},
                              new Result {DeviceId = 1, ActionType = 2},
                              new Result {DeviceId = 1, ActionType = 3},
                              new Result {DeviceId = 2, ActionType = 1},
                              new Result {DeviceId = 3, ActionType = 1},
                              new Result {DeviceId = 4, ActionType = 1},
                              new Result {DeviceId = 5, ActionType = 1},
                              new Result {DeviceId = 6, ActionType = 1},
                              new Result {DeviceId = 6, ActionType = 2},
                          };
        List<Result> result = results
            .GroupBy(x => x.DeviceId)
            .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();

        result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

public sealed class Result : IEqualityComparer<Result>
{
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }

    public int ActionType { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Result x, Result y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
        return x.DeviceId == y.DeviceId && x.ActionType == y.ActionType;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Result obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (obj.DeviceId*397) ^ obj.ActionType;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("DeviceId: {0}, ActionType: {1}", DeviceId, ActionType);
    }
}
```

Result output:

```
DeviceId: 2, ActionType: 1
DeviceId: 3, ActionType: 1
DeviceId: 4, ActionType: 1
DeviceId: 5, ActionType: 1
```